# unable to verify simulator build. Facebook Review Process

Tags: ios, facebook, ios-simulator

As per facebook review process we created a simulator build via command mentioned in there documentation.

when ever tried to verify simulator build. app launches and stuck at launch screen, with any alert "App can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software"

can anyone help us out from here.

As facebook review process fails with a reason and screen shot attached, that build can not be verified

Thanks in advance

Comment: This help? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/366546

Comment: yeah. working fine. verifying for further cases

Comment: it seems it that command to be run every time the file is downloaded. is there any way to make the file once, and it works fine everytime onwards its downloaded?

Comment: @UsmanNisar did you find a solution? We desperately need one now so we can get the permission to use

Comment: Hi @AndersEmil, didn't find a proper solution for simulator build. had to upload fresh build for every permission request submission.

Comment: @AndersEmil, but yes our permission request is approved. in last submission, we had added a detailed description in (Use Case section) about app and purpose of using permission including how requested permission will enhance user experience by allowing them additional activities using those permissions. hope that help you also

Comment: @UsmanNisar I don't understand, uploading a fresh build doesn't solve the problem of the quarantine on facebook's end. Did you ask the reviewer to remove the quarantine attribute or what?

Answer (score 2):

First need to install **Command-line App Launcher for Simulator** 
then you can verify simulator build via command

1. Press Command+Space and type Terminal and press enter/return key.

   2. Run in Terminal app:

   **ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null**

   3. and press enter/return key.
      If the screen prompts you to enter a password, please enter your Mac's user password to continue. When you type the password, it won't be displayed on screen, but the system would accept it. So just type your password and press ENTER/RETURN key. Then wait for the command to finish.
   4. Run:

   **brew install ios-sim**

   5. Done! You can now use **ios-sim**.